# MysqlQuery to get result which is not in table 2

Tags: mysql

I've two tables like

```
Table 1
-------------
id, name1
-------------
1, abc
2, xyz
3, hello
4, world


TABLE 2
--------------------------
id, table1_id, name2
--------------------------
1, 3, foo
2, 2, bar
```

Need mysqlQuery which will like (but not with subquery):

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 WHERE table1.id NOT IN (SELECT table2.id FROM table2);
```

And result like:

```
TABLE 1
-------------
id, name1
-------------
1, abc
4, world
```

Can you help me to get above result without subquery.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to achieve the results *with* a sub-query or *without* a sub-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and a WHERE clause with `IS NULL` to filter not matched records,

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.table1_id
WHERE b.table1_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id != b.id
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: let me check this query

Comment: My bad ... typo ... M Khalid Junaid's answer is correct. Edit: nvm .. i completely misread the question. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  select * from tab1 order by id asc limit 1;
  UNION
  select * from tab1 order by id desc  limit 1;
```

Comment: not worked UNION required same number of column in both tables.